# Flash AS3 linear gradient rotation issue

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, linear-gradients, gradient

This is my first post here so I hope I get everything right - and find an answer to my problem.

In Flash AS3 I'm creating a dynamic gradient in a rectangle. I need the gradient to have a rotation of 26 degrees. My problem is that the rotation seems to change based on the width/height of my rectangle. I need the rotation to be true 26 degrees no matter what size rectangle I apply it to.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var rect:Shape=new Shape();
this.addChild(rect);
rect.x=40;
rect.y=70;
var rectWidth:Number=200;
var rectHeight:Number=100;

drawShapes();

function drawShapes():void {
var mat:Matrix;
var colors:Array;
var alphas:Array;
var ratios:Array;
//We proceed to draw 'rect'.
mat=new Matrix();
colors=[0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0x001eff];
alphas=[1,1,1];
ratios=[0,120,255];

mat.createGradientBox(rectWidth,rectHeight,toRad(26));
rect.graphics.lineStyle();
rect.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR,colors,alphas,ratios,mat);
rect.graphics.drawRect(0,0,rectWidth,rectHeight);
rect.graphics.endFill();
}

function toRad(a:Number):Number {
return a*Math.PI/180;
}
```

Comment: Could you prove your point with some screenshots please?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line:

```
mat.createGradientBox(rectWidth,rectHeight,toRad(26));
```

Your gradient will change if the dimensions of the gradient box change. If you want your gradient to have always the same angle, keep the same gradient box dimensions regardless of your rectangle dimensions. To get gradient to be at an angle of 26 degrees (or whatever) I would also try to create a square gradient box, otherwise the angle of the gradient lines and the angle of rotation won't be equal.

Try out this code if see if this is what you are looking for:

```
import flash.display.Shape;

var rect:Shape;
var gradSize:uint = 100;

for(var i:uint=0;i<3;i++)
{
    rect = new Shape();
    this.addChild(rect);
    rect.x=20;
    rect.y=i*100+10;
    var rectWidth:Number=100+i*50;
    var rectHeight:Number=50;

    drawShapes(rect);
}

function drawShapes(rect:Shape):void
{
    var mat:Matrix;
    var colors:Array;
    var alphas:Array;
    var ratios:Array;
    //We proceed to draw 'rect'.
    mat=new Matrix();
    colors=[0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0x001eff];
    alphas=[1,1,1];
    ratios=[0,120,255];

    mat.createGradientBox(gradSize,gradSize,toRad(26));
    rect.graphics.lineStyle();
    rect.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR,colors,alphas,ratios,mat);
    rect.graphics.drawRect(0,0,rectWidth,rectHeight);
    rect.graphics.endFill();

}

function toRad(a:Number):Number
{
    return a*Math.PI/180;
}
```

You can play around with the width and height of the gradient box until you get the effect you want. Hope this helps!